# If connection fails, then MsgBox "There is no available connection." What command should 'connection fails' be replaced with?

Tags: windows-10, connection, vbscript

What command should 'connection fails' in the if-clause be replaced with?

```
createobject("wscript.shell").run "Rasdial connection_name account_name password",0

If connection fails, then 
MsgBox "There is no available connection."
End If
```

Comment: The suitable return value for run that would indicate an error.

Comment: How can I find out the return value?

Comment: Save the return value from that command to a variable and evaluate the variable. For debugging purposes you could also display it.

Comment: What is the command for saving the return value?

Comment: How do you expect to be able to make this usable without knowing how to handle variables? After all you will have to come up with some logic for the return value to evaluate it. As I said you'd use a variable. Maybe consider adding an explanation what your actual goal is and how have you tried getting the return value? See: [Declaring Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241.aspx)

Comment: The return value is unneeded in the code given by JosefZ below.

Comment: But it's using the return value in the form of `retValue`. That is actually a variable assignment. That code would error if you used `Option Explicit`. You would need to separately declare it using `Dim retValue`. A return value of zero for a program usually indicates successful execution. It's unlikely that you're stupid but rather didn't try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Run Method (Windows Script Host)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx);

> Runs a program in a new process.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> object.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn])
> ```
>
> **Arguments**
>
> - `object` - WshShell object.
> - `strCommand` - String value indicating the command line you want to run. You must include any parameters you want to pass to the
>     executable file.
> - `intWindowStyle` - Optional. Integer value indicating the appearance of the program's window. Note that not all programs make use of this
>     information.
> - `bWaitOnReturn` - Optional. Boolean value indicating whether the script should wait for the program to finish executing before
>     continuing to the next statement in your script. If set to *true*,
>     script execution halts until the program finishes, and `Run` returns
>     **any error code returned by the program**. If set to *false* (the default), the `Run` method returns immediately after starting the
>     program, automatically returning `0` (not to be interpreted as an
>     error code).

Next code snippet could work for you:

```
retValue = createobject("wscript.shell").run ( _
      "Rasdial connection_name account_name password",0 , True)

If retValue <> 0 then
    MsgBox "There is no available connection."
End If
```

Comment: Bingo! That's exactly what I want. It works perfectly although I had to change `# 0` to `<> 0`. Thank you very much, JosefZ. To be honest, I am too stupid to understand the article recommended by Seth above.